# How to write a for loop

Tags: matlab

I have already written a code and the code is in below:

```
r=16;
n=10;
w=[3 5]


R2=n;
R3=floor(r/w(2))*w(2);
R4=floor(r/w(3))*w(3);


[A2,padded]=vec2mat(vec(1:R2),w(1));
[A3,padded]=vec2mat(vec(R2+1:R2+R3),w(2));
```

i need to generate this code  for `A100`.So it will not look good if i write upto A100 by Hand.So i want to write this code by using `for loop.`I want to use `for loop` on `A` part where i generate `A2 - A10`

Matlab experts please need your help.

Comment: @ Dennis Jaheruddin-code is edited

Comment: Please try starting a new matlab session (or at least use `clear`), then paste this code. You will see that it still does not work.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention one variable.Now it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't have your stuff in separate variables, but in a data structure called "cell array" in MATLAB. If the values are all scalar ones, you can even use a "normal" array, aka matrix.

So for preparation, you do

```
R=56;
N=51;
W=[3 5 6 8 13 17 25 25 51];

R2=N; %//why that? are you sure?

RR = floor(R./W).*W;
%// So if you need this exception:
RR(1) = N;
%// or not, is up to you.

rows = cumsum(RR./W);

%//Now, whatever vec2mat returns, could be more than a simple scalar, so for AA we use
%//a cell array.

AA = repmat({[]}, 1, length(W));
offset=0;
for x=1:length(W)
    increment=RR(i)
    [AA{x},padded]=vec2mat(vec(offset+1:offset+increment),W(x));
    offset = offset+increment;
end
%%// Your AA values are now as well shifted by 1, so AA{1} is your old A2, and so on.
```

EDIT:

Find `RR` and `row` using vectorization as [Dan suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19404887/296974). But I don't think that the `AA` creation can be vectorized very good.

EDIT 2:

I just included Dan's solution into mine. It is likely that it brings a huge performance boost for large values of `length(W)`.

EDIT 3:

My code for your old question should give you the idea about the concepts; you can try to implement them for the new parts on your own. When you didn't succeed, you can ask about what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: +1 for `R2=N; %why that? are you sure?`, I was thinking exactly the same thing.

Comment: The value of This is the value of R2=51 that's why i write R2=N.

Comment: @glglgl Do you want to just replace your first 2 loops with my vectorized code? Then we can just leave your answer and remove mine since mine is incomplete anyway

Comment: @Dan Just did so, but I don't see a point for removing your answer.

Comment: I deleted. It adds nothing. Better to have it all in one answer like it is now.

Comment: @glglgl-I tried with you code but it shows error  -"Attempted to access R(2); index out of bounds because numel(R)=1.

Error in ==> Untitled2 at 63
    increment=R(x);"

Comment: @user2663126 I think it should be `increment=RR(i)`

Comment: @user2663126 Obviously, I misspelt one variable. As it was `RR` which I filled formerly, `RR` should be used here as well.

Comment: @glglgl Also probably RR(x) instead of RR(i)?

Comment: @Dan Thx, I missed that.